# (Given) A ∧ (B ∨ C) (To Prove) (A ∧ B) ∨ (A ∧ C)

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

This is what I did first[image](Given)          A ∧ (B ∨ C)

(To Prove)      (A ∧ B) ∨ (A ∧ C)

I have no idea how to make both sub proof same
[image]

I got it but I don't understand the logic behind it.

[Got it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CxyNV.png)

Comment: OK, what is the statement you want *after* the subproofs?

Comment: (A  ∧ B)  ∨  (A  ∧ C)

Comment: Exactly ... and the statement you get when applying $\lor$ Elim should be the very same statement that is at the end of each subproof ... So ...

Comment: Why am I able to add  (A  ∧ C) using  ∨Intro at 6th step?

Comment: Because $A \land B$ is true, and if $A \land B$ is true, then $(A \land B) \lor (A \land C)$ is also true.  And it follows the scheme of $\lor$ Intro: If $P$ is true, then $P \lor Q$ is true .. it's just that in this case the '$P$' is complex (it's $A \land B$), and the '$Q$' is complex as well (it's $A \land C$)

Comment: yeah understood, thank you very much for your effort and help!

Comment: You're welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several things go wrong here.

First and foremost, there is no need to start any subproofs with $A$ and $B \lor C$, since you can just infer those from the premise using $\land $ Elim

So, start with:

[image]

Second, make sure that you get the same line at the end of each subproof before applying $\lor$ Elim, so it'll look like this:

[image]

I'll let you figure out what that 'mystery' statement $Q$ should be ... but here's a hint: what statement would like like to have when all is said and done?

Finally, make sure you get $A \land C$, rather than $C \land A$ like you have on line 8. ... and of course get the disjuncts of the desired disjunction in the right order as well

Comment: So I only have to create two subproofs if the case is  A∨ (B ∧ C)?

Comment: @jkmnjik You don't have $A \lor (B \land C)$ but rather $A \land (B \lor C)$ So from that get $B \lor C$, and now do two subproofs: one on $B$ and one on $C$ ... like you already did ... just not within a subproof with $A$

Comment: cool got it, appreciate it!

Comment: @jkmnjik You got the whole proof?

Comment: I am dumb lol still stuck

Comment: @jkmnjik Post a new pic ...

Comment: Read the book, it will make life easy for you. Logic is fun, you just need to love it and you will understand it.